# Dart how to declare growable list of list

Tags: dart

I want to initialize a growable list of lists. Both the outer list and all the inner lists should be growable. I tried the following but they they don't work.

```
List<List<String>> fixturesOfLeagues = List<List<String>>();
List<List<String>> fixturesOfLeagues = [];
List<List<String>> fixturesOfLeagues = [[]];
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What makes them not work? `List`s in Dart are growable by default. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/List-class.html

Comment: each inner list needs to be created before being added to.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPhillips that did the trick. I should have added a new empty inner list before adding element into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you need to create each list separately and add them to them list of lists.

They are growable by default, according to the [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/List-class.html):

> The default growable list, as returned by new List() or [], keeps an internal buffer, and grows that buffer when necessary.

Example use of the code above:

```
void main() {

  List<List<String>> fixturesOfLeagues = List<List<String>>();

  for (int i=0; i < 5 ; i++){
    List<String> ListToBeAdded = ['$i'];
    fixturesOfLeagues.add(ListToBeAdded); //create a list and adds to the outter list.
  }

  print(fixturesOfLeagues);

  fixturesOfLeagues[2].add('test');

  print(fixturesOfLeagues);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
[[0], [1], [2, test], [3], [4]]
```

Comment: The outer list is still not growable. I had to do this: `List<List<String>> fixturesOfLeagues = List.generate(1, (i) => []);`